# Apache/Wsgi - trouble switching from local environment to virtualenv on CentOS

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to move an existing, working django app from using the local env (i.e. /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages) to using a virtualenv instead (i.e. [PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV]/lib/python2.7/site-packages). This is meant to help me with package updates eventually, so I can roll back to a previous env if necessary.

I started by installing on a fresh virtualenv all of the packages installed in the local env, using the exact same versions. At this point I am able to run the django shell form within the app dir (/home/django/qa/web) using the new env, which should confirm that all dependencies are met.

Below are the initial, working configurations.

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "web.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName qa.myserv.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/qa.myserv.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/qa.myserv.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/qa.myserv.com/logs/requests.log combined

    <Directory /home/django/qa/web/web>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess qa python-path=/home/django/qa/web:/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup qa
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/qa/web/web/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I tried getting this to work with the virtual env, which is located at `/home/django/env/qa_0`, by changing the `WSGIDaemonProcess` row:

**Attempt 1**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess qa python-path=/home/django/qa/web:/home/django/env/qa_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This resulted in an Internal Server Error, with the following in the error log:

```
[Wed Apr 25 13:57:25.089794 2018] [:error] [pid 23812] [remote 192.168.1.248:240]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Apr 25 13:57:25.089845 2018] [:error] [pid 23812] [remote 192.168.1.248:240] ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

**Attempt 2**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess qa python-home=/home/django/env/qa_0 python-path=/home/django/qa/web
```

This also resulted in an Internal Server Error, taking longer this time, and ending with the following in the error log:

```
[Wed Apr 25 13:30:58.779124 2018] [core:error] [pid 17503] [client 192.168.1.248:53731] Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py
```

I reviewed the django and modwsgi docs as best as I could, as well as looking at every related question I could find on stack overflow, I can't seem to figure this out. Any Ideas?

Comment: Try adding ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``. You are likely using a Python package which doesn't work in sub interpreters. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton, I will try that, but which version of the `WSGIDaemonProcess` should I use, if any? Also, does it matter if I put the `WSGIApplicationGroup` directive before or after it?

Comment: What do you mean by "which version of the WSGIDaemonProcess should I use"? Do you mean which version of mod_wsgi? You can add ``WSGIApplicationGroup`` on next line after ``WSGIProcessGroup``. Ordering doesn't matter as long as in scope that Apache will apply it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton what I meant was which of my "attempts", 1 or 2 is the correct setting? The first only defines the `python-path` and the second also defines `python-home`, and they fail in different ways. I was wondering which seemed more correct to you (in addition to adding the `WSGIApplicationGroup` as you suggested).

Comment: The one using ``python-home``. You should avoid using ``python-path`` to refer to ``site-packages`` directory. Details of recommended method in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, I tried using "attempt 2" (with the `python-home` directive), and adding `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`. The result is still "Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py"... Any other ideas? Is there a way to troubleshoot/debug these settings in a controlled manner, so I can see exactly what fails?

Comment: Set ``LogLevel info`` so mod_wsgi logs more about process restarts. Determine from that why the daemon process was restarted if it was. Check also for ``Segmentation fault`` error message in main Apache error log.

Comment: Set ``threads=5`` and ``request-timeout=15`` option on ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` directive. That reduces number of threads but also sets a timeout. If requests get stuck, then daemon process will be automatically restarted and Python stack trace will be logged as to where is getting stuck. Timeout will occur between 15 seconds and 1 min 15 seconds after stuck request was started (it varies for reasons related to use of multiple threads). Ensure though you are using recent mod_wsgi version and not ancient version supplied by operating system packages.

Comment: Reason for variability of when request timeout occurs can be seen in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html against documentation for ``request-timeout`` option.